# TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'audio_volume.toPrecision(2)') in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I decided to split this question, as it turned out it was multiple problems in one. I fixed the TypeError with a parseFloat(), however the code does not work, so I made a separate question.

---

I am getting the error:

"TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'audio_volume.toPrecision(2)')"

On this bit of code:

```
var audio_volume = myAudio.volume;
alert(audio_volume);
document.getElementById("Volume_Read").innerHTML = audio_volume.toPrecision(2);
```

I used the alert line to make sure it's reading the volume, and it works fine. For some reason it's complaining about `.toPrecision(2)`, I think. This code works fine in Chrome, IE, and Firefox. It's just in Safari that it doesn't work (so far -- I haven't tested it in Opera).

Comment: Use `console.log(audio_volume)` instead to get a better idea of what it really is.  Is it a actual number? Or perhaps something else, like a string?

Comment: This code: `alert(console.log(myAudio.volume));
            var audio_volume = parseFloat(myAudio.volume);
            alert(console.log(audio_volume));
            ` lists it as undefined, both times.

Comment: `alert(console.log(myAudio.volume))` will always show `undefined`, because `console.log()` _returns_ `undefined`. Look in your javascript console for the result of `console.log`.

Comment: I see. It works fine. myAudio.volume is a string and parseFloat(myAudio.volume) is a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason, it sounds like `myAudio.volume` isn't returning a number in Safari, and instead returning some other kind of object that does not have a `toPrecision` method.

So try to convert the value to a number before you use it.

```
var audio_volume = parseFloat(myAudio.volume);
```

---

UPDATE: http://jsfiddle.net/vxDVp/

That's proof that it works just like you expect... Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Good suggestion, however, it didn't solve the problem, although it worked on a refresh, after refreshing again, it stopped working again. This is rather bizarre. It's a clean install of Safari, too (just installed it).

Comment: What is `myAudio`? What is the result of `console.log(typeof myAudio.volume)`? Help us help you here, we need a bit more info...

Comment: `console.log(typeof myAudio.volume)` is undefined. It's also undefined after the `parseFloat(myAudio.volume)` myAudio is the getElementById of an audio element (`<audio></audio>`)

Comment: So here a very simple recreation of your problem.  This works for me in Chrome and Safari: http://jsfiddle.net/vxDVp/1/ If it works for you, then you problem lies somewhere else in your code.

Comment: It works in Chrome, as expected. However, in Safari it doesn't work. I'm going to try restarting my computer to see if it works. This is strange, as I just installed Safari not too long ago to test this out.

Comment: What version of Safari? Windows or Mac? Does your version support the audio tag?

Comment: It's 5.1.7. I just restarted my computer and the code works on the first time it loads, then it stops working permanently, on every page. Also, I rechecked out your code and that code does work on Safari, however, this still returns undefined: http://jsfiddle.net/vxDVp/3/

Comment: That's expected... I pasted this comment above on your question: `alert(console.log(myAudio.volume))` will always show `undefined`, because `console.log()` returns `undefined`. Look in your javascript console for the result of `console.log`.

Comment: I see why it was undefined. Actually, it works fine (http://jsfiddle.net/vxDVp/7/). I don't know why Safari claims it to be undefined. Perhaps it has something to do with loading the audio tag?

Comment: Interestingly, now Safari does not return an error in the log. It just doesn't work at all. However, other links work, so it's not the link.

Comment: Whatever is happening, I'm willing to bet it's localized to your computer. Unfortunately.

Comment: That's strange. I wrote up the full code http://jsfiddle.net/RzrMh/1/ However, it doesn't work in jsfiddle. I'd like to doubt it's my computer. I can't see why anything would prevent the code from working. However, in jsFiddle, it's doing the same thing as in Safari, but not Chrome (not doing anything)

Comment: I separated the questions, as apparently there are two problems. This solution fixed the error that was being displayed, but since the code still does not work in Safari (also it does not work in jsFiddle), I've separated the question.

Comment: Can you link to the other question? I'm having the same issue. I had the error, error went away, now there's still no audio in Safari, but Chrome plays it.